# $\frac{(n+1)\log 2}{\log(2n + 2)} \ge \frac{x \log 2}{2 \log x}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Show for $$16 \le 2n \lt x \le 2n+2$$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$)  that $$\frac{(n+1)\,\mathrm{log}\,2}{\mathrm{log}(2n + 2)} \ge \frac{x\, \mathrm{log} \,2}{2\, \mathrm{log}\, x}$$

I can derive only $$\frac{(n+1)\,\mathrm{log}\,2}{\mathrm{log}(2n + 2)} \ge \frac{x}{2\, \mathrm{log}\, x}$$ I suspect something may be wrong in my propositions. (As you might guess, I try to verify the derivation of the Tshebyshev estimation given [here](https://www.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/Schulportal/Lehrerfortbildungen/TermineUndMaterial/tschebyscheff.pdf), page 4. This question has been asked [already](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150840/understanding-the-proof-behind-pix-ge-frac-log-22-fracx-log-x) but as far as I can see, left unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f:[e,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{2\log(x)}$ is an ascending function.

If $2n<x\le 2n+2$, we have $f(2n)\lt f(x)\le f(2n+2)$. That means $  \dfrac{x}{2\log(x)} \le \dfrac{2n+2}{2 \log(2n+2)}$ which implies the result  $\dfrac{x}{2\log(x)}\log(2) \le \dfrac{(n+1)}{\log(2n+2)}\log(2)$.

Comment: Thats really mean, it looks as if the result is almost trivial but then ... thx!